# MobileVLCKit Not work with Live555 library

Tags: c++, ios, rtsp, libvlc, live555

I need MobileVLCKit player and live555 streamer both in same ios project.

I successfully build library and merge into same iOS project. But VLC player getting crashed at below line on code in live555.cpp

`error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbadd9b286bcebea0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

At source code in file live555.cpp
`p_sys->rtsp->sendOptionsCommand( &continueAfterOPTIONS, &authenticator );`

live555.cpp file path in MobileVLCKit
MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/modules/access/live555.cpp

Please help me. I am struct here from last 2-3 days.

Comment: I got the same error. Now you got the answer? If you got please share me.

Answer (score 0):

MobileVLCKit includes liblive555 as well so assuming that you are statically linking, only one can win due to symbol collisions. Consider to link MobileVLCKit dynamically instead or make sure to include liblive555 only once per binary.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I know that live555 library also used in MobileVLCKit for player. I have added MobileVLCKit Dynamic framework, But still streamer and player crash unexpectedly.
Now try to link live555 dynamically to project also. I think both will work with dynamic linking.